# Restricting access to a website on IIS with groups

Tags: iis-7, .net, windows-authentication

I'm trying to set up our websites to only allow access from users in certain AD groups using windows authentication but i can't seem to make it work. I've tried using IIS's authorization and restricting it to those groups only, but i don't have access from users that are in those groups. This seems like something that's supported, but I can't get it to work.

The pages are completely in .net as well, so i've tried specifying

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="Domain\ProgramUsers"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

in the web.config but then it allows people in who aren't part of the Program Users group, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify:

```
Deny users="*"
```

At the moment you're blocking access only to non-authenticated users, i.e. regardless of group membership.

Comment: At that point i'm unable to access the site from either user.

Comment: Try including `<identity impersonate="true"/>` before the authorization node

Comment: Already have it. I'll add that to the above information. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hmm.. ok.  Couple of other things to try: check the case of your domain and group name - it believe the case needs to be correct e.g. ProgramUsers not programusers.  Also, and forgive me this is not meant to be patronizing but is this definitely a security group and not a distribution group?

Comment: Ah! Lightbulb moment. Try `<allow roles="domain\group"/>` rather than `<allow users="domain\group"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<allow roles="domain\group"/>` instead of `<allow users="domain\group"/>` like mikrose suggested. It's how we have it setup on some of our internal sites and it seems to be working for us along with the `<deny users="*"/>` and we do not have impersonate explicitly set.